# OnTouch change Image in XML - android

Tags: xml, imageview, selector

I have an xml file in the drawable folder which I want to use as a ImageView src. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home2" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/home1"></item>
</selector>
```

As you can see I want that everytime the image is pressed, it will change the image to another image but for some reason it doesn't work properly. It just shows me the default image and when I press the image, it isn't switched.

Also, I tried to put this code but I get the same result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/home2" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/home1"></item>
</selector>
```

What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You mean for example before press image=home1 when pressed image=home2 and when user release pressing image=home2 that it wont change again.
If it is like this you can use this code.

```
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/home2" />
```